# Executing Query against SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I'm trying to query some data from SQLite in C#, although nothing returns [and it should return data from this table]

This is the part in the code I try to connect to SQLite and perform the query. As I mentioned no data returns. I tried INSERT as well and no entry is added.

```
SetConnection();                        
sql_con.Open();                    
myQuery = "Select * from myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '" + myName+ "%';"; 
sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();       
sql_cmd.CommandText = myQuery;            
rw_maxid = (long)sql_cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
sql_con.Close();
```

What is wrong with this code? Any advices/documentation/corrections?

Comment: Use SQLiteParameters to start with, gives you a more clear query + prevents sql injection.

Comment: is that typing mistake `xtQuery` and `txtQuery`?

Comment: @Max Mommersteeg: Any examples of SQLiteParameters?

Comment: There's a gaping SQL Injection flaw in your query here.  You should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: Echo your sql to see what you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

How are you debugging?
A scalar query only returns the first column of the first row
This assumes the column you want to get a max from is named id and is a long

```
try 
{
   SetConnection();                        
   sql_con.Open();                    
   sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand(); 

   myQuery = "Select max(id) from myTable;"; 
   Debug.WriteLine(myQuery);      
   sql_cmd.CommandText = myQuery;            
   rw_maxid = (long)sql_cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   myQuery = "Select max(id) from myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '" + myName+ "%';"; 
   Debug.WriteLine(myQuery);      
   sql_cmd.CommandText = myQuery;            
   rw_maxid = (long)sql_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(Ex.message);
} 
finally 
{
   sql_con.Close();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting data from sqlite database:

```
public DataTable GetValueFromDatabase(string query)
{
    const string connectionString = "Data Source=DatabaseName;Version=3;";
    using(var ds = new DataSet())
    {
        using(var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
        {
            using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
            {
                ds.Clear();
                da.Fill(ds);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                tran.Complete();
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above method returns a DataTable, where you can grab the value from.
This solution however doesn't offer a solution to the sql injection problem!

Call the function like:

```
var dt = GetValueFromDatabase("Select * from myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '" + myName+ "%';");
```

Comment: Error 14 The type or namespace name 'TransactionScope' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Dalek try adding this at the top of code: `using System.Transactions;`

Comment: also add:  using System.Transactions;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SQLite; and in the terminal run: "dotnet add package System.Data.SQLite.Core"